# pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: Parquet data source does not support void data type

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, types, parquet, void

I am trying to add a column in my dataframe `df1` in PySpark.

The code I tried:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df1 = df1.withColumn("empty_column", F.lit(None))
```

But I get this error:

> pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: Parquet data source does not support void data type.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Instead of just `F.lit(None)`, use it with a `cast` and a proper data type. E.g.:

```py
F.lit(None).cast('string')
```

```py
F.lit(None).cast('double')
```

---

When we add a literal null column, it's data type is *void*:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
spark.range(1).withColumn("empty_column", F.lit(None)).printSchema()
# root
#  |-- id: long (nullable = false)
#  |-- empty_column: void (nullable = true)
```

But when saving as parquet file, *void* data type is not supported, so such columns must be `cast` to some other data type.